# Free sliders that use srcset to select the appropiate image

Tags: wordpress, slider, srcset

Please could you tell me the names of free Wordpress sliders that use srcset.
E.g. if 3 images are generated from one image to serve desktop,tablet and mobile the slider will pick up the correct one based on the form factor of the user's machine and so reduce downloads on mobiles.  I tried Smart Slider 3 and Metaslider but could not see how they used srcset.

I have previously used http://slippry.com/ with srcset on a non Wordpress site and may try this if nothing else is available.

I am new to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the cropping in metaslider.
Srcset will work after this.